# Should this question really be flagged?

Tags: support, downvotes, vote-to-close, close-reasons, downvote-reason

I stumbled upon this question:

[image: question]

Granted, it's not a very good question. As pointed out in comments below, it is technically not even a question, but it is very obvious what the question should have been. ("How do I do this?") And it shows very little (or no) effort, so I completely understand the downvotes.

But it has two votes for unclear and one vote for to broad. Is this really correct?

- It is very clear what OP wants. OP wants said while loop in an equivalent recursive variant. Therefore it cannot be unclear.
- The problem is specific. As I mentioned in the previous bullet point, OP wants a recursive variant of a while loop. Therefore it cannot be to broad.

I also looked at other close reasons. It's not off-topic, since it is a perfectly legal programming question, and it's not opinion-based either. Maybe it could be a dup, but let's assume it is not.

Am I right here? That this question is correct to downvote, but not to closevote?

Comment: It... isn't a question. but a quick edit could fix that

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I agree. Technically it is not a question, but it is very obvious what the question should be.

Comment: @klutt the people answering the question should not have to imply the question or what the questioner is trying to say.

Comment: Are they asking how to do so? or are they trying to do so and running into a problem they forgot to mention. We can assume the former... but the question itself doesn't specify which.

Comment: Hmmm, I must say that I get a bit curious about the downvotes to this question.

Comment: Meta votes are not the same as SO votes, it normally means disagreement.

Comment: 'I want to cut my grass with scissors, please help me'.

Comment: I didn't downvote the recursion question.  I was too lazy to move the mouse, and it was too hard to imagine how such a Q&A might be useful to future users/visitors.   So, I let it go as todays 'welcoming' effort.

Answer (score 11):

So what problem are they having writing the recursive function that they need?  Do they not know how to write a recursive function?  Is their recursive function producing the wrong value, is it not ending, what?

Those who marked the question as Unclear were presumably indicating that the question was not clear as to what they were struggling with with respect to trying to solve that problem.

Those who marked it as Too Broad were presumably indicating that trying to cover all of the possible aspects of the problem that the author might not understand would be outside of the scope of an SO answer.

Answer (score 9):

As it is... The post is most definitely "Too Broad" and arguably "Unclear."

To start with, we have no idea what exactly they expect the answer to be. There may be many ways to answer their question properly. Both of those points make it "Too Broad" because there are many possible answers, and some could argue the first makes the post "Unclear."

Next, this reads like a "Here's my requirement, give me the result" post, which is inherently too broad. We don't do work requests, and this reads a lot like one.

You say it's obviously a "How do I" question, but that's not true. It *could be* a "How do I" question, but to me, and likely many others, this reads instead like I said before, a "Gimme teh codez" as it is commonly called.

If the asker has tried and hit a snag, they need to include what they've tried so others don't duplicate their effort. If they need to know how to do it, they need to specify that. There's just not enough to adequately, and *briefly*, answer this question at the moment.